# Flex item collapsing margin when other flex item has an overflow: auto;

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is a strange one which I believe just started happening so not sure if it's a new bug in Chrome. Firefox and IE10+ are fine.

Basically, I have a flex item with margin-left: auto which pushes it right. Works fine.

However, when another flex item has content with a overflow being evoked, it seems to collapse the margin on render. When you move the browser it corrects itself. Weird!?

Any idea's Front Enders?

Note: You may have to refresh the example a few times because 25% of the time it seems to render o.k.

http://codepen.io/rhysyg03/pen/rePgQY

```
<h3>Working Example</h3>
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex__item">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <span>Custom Dropdown</span>
      <div class="dropdown__content">
        <div style="height:40px; border:1px solid red;">Dropdown Content overflow not being evoked</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex__item  flex__item--right ">Right</div>
</div>

<h3>Broken Example</h3>
<div class="flex  mb">
  <div class="flex__item">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <span>Custom Dropdown</span>
      <div class="dropdown__content">
        <div style="height:100px; border:1px solid red;">Dropdown Content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex__item  flex__item--right ">Right</div>
</div>

.flex {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  border:1px solid;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex__item--right {
  margin-left: auto;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown__content {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.mb {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in the latest version of Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 m

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in a proper way, i have to admit that i dont know.

But i've remarcked something :

- When you change your CSS during the process, Chrome is working. It only bugs when you reload the page.

Knowing that, we can try to make some things to "get around" the problem.

You can add JQuery library and add some scripts you want to load with your html page.

```
<body onload="scriptName()">
```

then you want to attribute another css style to this element :

```
function scriptName(){
   document.getElementById("flex__item--right").style.margin-left="auto";
}
```

This is not the best way to fix it, but it should work for a time.

Comment: Hey thanks for giving it a shot but yeah hopefully looking for a CSS answer.